# Why are all of my labels blank on this Windows Form?

Tags: winforms, label

I’m trying to show and hide a pop-up when certain events occur.  The pop-up is appearing and disappearing properly, but all of its labels are blank.  I originally was trying to populate the labels prior to showing the form, but I’ve commented-out all of that logic.  The labels are all blank, but the space is properly allocated for each label (see screenshot).

my popup control:

```
public MyPopUp()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

my separate class:

```
MyPopUp _MyPopUp;

protected override void OnLoad(IServiceProvider myServiceProvider)
{
    _MyPopUp = new MyPopUp();
}

protected override void WhenSomethingHappens() {
    _MyPopUp.Show();
}

protected override void WhenSomethingElseHappens() {
    _MyPopUp.Hide();
}
```

Here is part of my designer.cs file.  I've only copy/pasted the code from one of the labels, but the other 5 labels on the form have nearly-identical code.

```
private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;

private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
    this.SuspendLayout();
    // 
    // label1
    // 
    this.label1.AutoSize = true;
    this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(58, 9);
    this.label1.Name = "label1";
    this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(41, 13);
    this.label1.TabIndex = 0;
    this.label1.Text = "Some Label Text"; 
    // 
    // MyPopUp
    // 
    this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
    this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
    this.Name = "MyPopUp";
    this.Text = "Some Text";
    this.ResumeLayout(false);
    this.PerformLayout();
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: If you commented out the populating logic, where are you expecting the text to come from? Do the lables have an initial text that you set in the form designer? It's hard to say, if you don't show the code that populates the lables.

Comment: maybe you should set the `BackgroundColor` of the labels to `Transparent`

Comment: Yes Oliver, the labels all have initial values defined in MyPopUp.Designer.cs

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes , I've included code for one of the labels.

Answer (score 3):

You need to call Refresh() function to force every child control to invalidate, i.e. redraw, its client area.

For your case:

```
protected override void WhenSomethingHappens() {
    _MyPopUp.Show();
    _MyPopUp.Refresh();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are running the form modelessly.

If you want to you can check that your font/background colours are good etc. by running it Modally:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(YourFormName);
```

then add the DoEvent line to your modeless call:

```
Form2 F2 = new Form2();
F2.Show();
System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
```

and that should do it!

Comment: After trying out almost 98 links. This amazing answer solved my problem. Thanks @Louise.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a test and found a possibility to make the Label Text disappear. The Label Text disappears if the `ForeColor` is the same as the `BackColor`. From your Label-adding code, I see that you didn't specify these colors. WinForms Controls inherit a lot of properties from the parent control (in this case the Form itself), if they are not defined. This probably means that `ForeColor` and `BackColor` of the Form are the same and this propagates to the labels. Either change the `ForeColor` color of the Form or of the Label to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to invoke before showing the form, this way the form will be created in the main thread.

```
if (this.InvokeRequired)
            this.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => //'this.' is the form
            {
                _MyPopUp.Show();
            }));
```